# Gunicorn + Nginx Internal server error while trying to apply code changes

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I set up a VPS (django + gunicorn + nginx ) and it was working fine showing default django screen, but after I updated my django code and made all migrations I thought that now I need to restart gunicorn to apply changes.

So I did this:

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```

After this I've got `Internal Server Error`
Everything is set up like [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

gunicorn.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.targett

[Service]
User=thekotik
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/thekotik/glboy
ExecStart=/home/thekotik/glboy/denv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/thekotik/glboy/closer.sock closer.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: check logs (if you have - Gunicorn and Nginx should creat logs automatically) or run in debug mode to see more inforamation.

Comment: @furas error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228

Comment: @furas tried  chown thekotik /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py': Operation not permitted

Comment: I usually use `service gunicorn restart` to apply code changes. It works fine for me

Comment: @Vinand attach the gunicorn service file with question, that will make things clear to others

Comment: @sideffect0 attached gunicorn.service in edit

Answer (score 0):

`<class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 13] Permission denied: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228`

unix socket files holds the same case unix file permissions; the file ( `/home/thekotik/glboy/closer.sock`) is currently being used or not owned by gunicorn process user that causes `error 13`.

I recommend using the TCP option `--bind 127.0.0.1:8000`.For tcp based changes,

**gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.targett

[Service]
User=thekotik
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/thekotik/glboy
ExecStart=/home/thekotik/glboy/denv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 127.0.0.1:9090 closer.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

use above systemd service file for gunicorn & change the proxy option in nginx to

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090$request_uri;
```

that will avoid unix socket file based permission problems.